# Background zooms in incorrectly when following mouse movement

Tags: javascript

I've created a button, when you hover over it a div with a background image enlarges. The background should follow the cursor's movements. Meaning that the background image follows your cursor as you hover over the button.

When I hover over the bottom right part of the button, the image will zoom in to the top left before moving to the cursor's location. Check out the example below to see what I mean. I'd like to make it zoom directly to the cursor's location, any ideas?

```js
var imgZoomIn = 1.2; //% of how much the image will enlarge

function buttonImgResize(x, e){
    //Location of the cursor (as percentage of the container's size)
    var imgContPosition = x.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mousePosX = (e.clientX - imgContPosition.left) / x.offsetWidth;
    var mousePosY = (e.clientY - imgContPosition.top) / x.offsetHeight;
    
    //Finding how far to move the image from top and left
    var leftImgOverlap = x.offsetWidth * (imgZoomIn - 1) * mousePosX;
    var topImgOverlap = x.offsetHeight * (imgZoomIn - 1) * mousePosY;
    
    //implementing changes
    x.firstElementChild.style.left = 0 - leftImgOverlap + "px";
    x.firstElementChild.style.top = 0 - topImgOverlap + "px";
}

//Reseting values
function buttonImgDownsize(x){
    x.firstElementChild.style.left = "0";
    x.firstElementChild.style.top = "0";
}
```

```css
/*Container*/
.showCaseBtn{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; height: 300px;
}
/*div with background image*/
.showcaseBtn_Back{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: black no-repeat center center / cover;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.showCaseBtn:hover .showcaseBtn_Back{
    height: 120%; width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="showCaseBtn" onmousemove="buttonImgResize(this, event)" onmouseout="buttonImgDownsize(this)">
  <div class="showcaseBtn_Back" style="background-image: url(https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/need-for-speed/common/2017/10/nfs-payback-jaguar-f-type-2x.jpg.adapt.1920w.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to add comments, will do that immediatly

Comment: Isn't it will be easier to have container with `overflow: hidden` and normal image with `position: absolute` that you will be able to move around by using `top` and `left` and resize by using `width` and `height`?

Comment: @Flying I would have tried to do that but I think it would've been much more of a hassle to centre and contain the image within the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the css transition. If you remove it, the zooming works but no fancy scaling will happen.

```js
var imgZoomIn = 1.2;

function buttonImgResize(x, e){
    var imgContPosition = x.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mousePosX = (e.clientX - imgContPosition.left) / imgContPosition.width;
    var mousePosY = (e.clientY - imgContPosition.top) / imgContPosition.height;
    
    var leftImgOverlap = imgContPosition.width * (imgZoomIn - 1) * mousePosX;
    var topImgOverlap = imgContPosition.height * (imgZoomIn - 1) * mousePosY;
    
    
    x.firstElementChild.style.left = - leftImgOverlap + "px";
    x.firstElementChild.style.top =  - topImgOverlap + "px";
}

function buttonImgDownsize(x){
    x.firstElementChild.style.left = "0";
    x.firstElementChild.style.top = "0";
}
```

```css
.showCaseBtn{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; height: 300px;
}
.showcaseBtn_Back{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: black no-repeat center center / cover;
}
.showCaseBtn:hover .showcaseBtn_Back{
    height: 120%; width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="showCaseBtn" onmousemove="buttonImgResize(this, event)" onmouseout="buttonImgDownsize(this)">
  <div class="showcaseBtn_Back" style="background-image: url(https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/need-for-speed/common/2017/10/nfs-payback-jaguar-f-type-2x.jpg.adapt.1920w.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. disappointed this didn't work like I'd wish though.